# Some Flutter packages cause gradle error when trying to build the project

Tags: flutter

When I create a new project and try to run it, it's working fine, but some packages cause gradle error. For example, I tried to test `Flutter_Chat_UI` package from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_chat_ui). There is an example project that can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/flyerhq/flutter_chat_ui/tree/main/example). When I try to run this project, the following error is shown:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'.
>
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:classpath'.
> > Could not find gradle-7.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1).
> > Searched in the following locations: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.2.1/gradle-7.2.1.jar
> > Could not find builder-7.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:7.2.1).
> > Searched in the following locations:
> > https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/7.2.1/builder-7.2.1.jar
> > Could not find protos-30.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:30.2.1).
> > Searched in the following locations:
> > https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/30.2.1/protos-30.2.1.jar
> > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
>
> - Try:
>
> > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> > Run with --scan to get full insights.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: when i meet these kind of error, i often open Android Studio & XCode for native code, then try to run and see what native code happened. Most of times, those errors are more specific than Flutter one & easier to solve.